# Clipping when drawing dots using cairo

Tags: c, graphics, png, cairo

I've got a simple Cairo program that attempts to draw a diagonal consisting of dots in a 600x600 PNG.  However, the output appears to be truncated whenever I attempt to render all of the dots using a single call to cairo_stroke().

Specifically, consider the following program:

```
#include <cairo/cairo.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cairo_surface_t *surface =
        cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 300, 300);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
    cairo_set_line_cap(cr, CAIRO_LINE_CAP_ROUND);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 5);
    for (double x = 0.0; x <= 300; x += 10) {
        cairo_move_to(cr, x, x);
        cairo_close_path(cr);
        cairo_stroke(cr);
    }
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "output.png");
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    return 0;
}
```

which generates the following correct output:

[image: here]

If I move the

```
cairo_stroke(cr);
```

outside of the for loop, then the following incorrect output is generated instead:

[image: output].

Can someone else explain why the second attempt fails?  I suspect I must be doing something wrong here...

Comment: As a note, the choice of point drawing was based on the post given [here](http://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2009-June/017459.html).  However, changing `cairo_close_path(cr)` to `cairo_line_to(cr, x, x)` seems to be just fine.

Comment: What cairo version are you using? This seems to work fine here with cairo 1.11.4. Perhaps you are hitting a cairo bug which was already fixed?

Comment: Drawing points as zero-length lines is a *trick*. More correct is to draw filled arcs.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <cairo/cairo.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        cairo_surface_t *surface =
            cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 300, 300);

        cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
        cairo_set_line_cap(cr, CAIRO_LINE_CAP_ROUND);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
        cairo_set_line_width(cr, 5);

        for (double x = 0.0; x <= 300; x += 10) {
            cairo_move_to(cr, x, x);
            cairo_close_path(cr);
        }

        cairo_stroke(cr); /* moved here */

        cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "output.png");
        cairo_destroy(cr);
        cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

        return 0;
    }
```

Moving `cairo_stroke(cr)` outside the for-loop seems to generate equal output with Cairo version 1.10.1.

Compiled as: gcc test.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0` -std=c99 -lcairo